# parameter of compareTo and implicit typecast

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Employee(String name, int id, int age )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.empId = id;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return empId;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}

class SortById extends Employee implements Comparable<SortById>
{
    public SortById(String name, int id, int age)
    {
        super(name, id, age);
    }
    public int compareTo(SortById other)
    {
        if (this.getId() > other.getId()) return 1;
        if (this.getId() < other.getId()) return -1;
        return 0;

    }
}

class SortByName extends Employee implements Comparable<SortByName>
{
    public SortByName(String name, int id, int age)
    {
        super(name, id, age);
    }

    public int compareTo(SortByName other)
    {
        if (this.getName().compareTo(other.getName()) > 0) return 1;
        if (this.getName().compareTo(other.getName()) < 0) return -1;
        return 0;

    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee[] array = new SortById[3];
        array[0] = new SortById("Gautam", 1222, 20);
        array[1] = new SortById("Shivam", 1221, 20);
        array[2] = new SortById("Ankit", 1223, 21);
        System.out.println(array[0] instanceof SortByName);

        Arrays.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.println("ID: " + array[i].getId() + " Name: " + array[i].getName() + " Age: " + array[i].getAge());
        Employee[] array2 = new SortByName[3];
        array2[0] = new SortByName("Gautam", 1222, 20);
        array2[1] = new SortByName("Shivam", 1221, 20);
        array2[2] = new SortByName("Ankit", 1223, 21);
        Arrays.sort(array2);
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
            System.out.println("ID: " + array2[i].getId() + " Name: " + array2[i].getName() + " Age: " + array2[i].getAge());

    }
}
```

This program runs fine, I just wanted to ask since I'm using the parameterized version of `Comparable`, should the reference I pass into the `compareTo` be of `SortById` type or `SortByName` type?

The code runs fine even if the reference is of type `Employee`, although pointing to its subclass (`SortByName` or `SortById`).

How is an implicit cast happening? I have read is not possible i.e., it's not possible to cast a superclass type to subclass implicitly.

Comment: All `Employee` instances in your arrays have actual type `SortById` or `SortByName`. If you add a `new Employee(String, int, int)` to the array you'll get errors.

Comment: The JVM determine the real type of the object at runtime. Since you created them via `new SortByName()`, the JVM knows it is the correct type even though you hold the reference as an Employee

Comment: @jalynn2 isn't implicit casting happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `compareTo` which explains why you don't need the cast. The actual call is within `Arrays.sort` which takes care of it (by actually using the raw `Comparable`)

Also, in such a case the compiler will generate 2 `compareTo` methods: the one you explicitly define with the `SortByXX` parameter, and another one with an `Object` parameter which delegates to the first one.

As @martijno says it, you will run into problems if you add a simple `Employee` in your array, which will lead to `ClassCastException` (from `Employee` to either `Comparable` or `SortByXX`). Same will occur if you mix `SortByName` and `SortById`.

Comment: so object type matters, not the reference type(it may be super/sub class) in this case?

Comment: and does during internal implementation of compareTo method(as you said it will take care of),  casts it to its subclass here automatically, before passing in, since you were right, when i called compareTo method myself, it produced an error.

Comment: The variable (or expression) type matters at compilation time, as long as you call the method! If you use an (allowed) explicit cast, then the object type will be checked at runtime. The generated `compareTo(Object)` indeed performs an explicit cast to delegate to `compareTo(SortByXX)`.